# return custom struct as python object(which aslo could be none) in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, option-type, pybind11

I want to return a custom struct as a python object, which also could be none. I have tried two API:

```
struct Database {
  UserModel *get_user1(const std::string &user_name) const;
  std::optional<UserModel> get_user2(const std::string &user_name) const;
};
```

But it seems none of these two API works.
Would you please help me?

Comment: What do you want to return? `DataBase` or `UserModel`?

Comment: @Nimrod, return `UserModel` as a python object, and it could be a python `None`. API `get_user` is a method of `Database`, which is also a python object.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's my mistake. I didn't fetch the correct data element in mysql C connector's result set.

My C++ compiler/runtime(macOS clang-12) didn't throw any exception when I use the pybind11 built module.

And finally, both of these two API works correctly after I fix my bug:

- `UserModel *get_user1(const std::string &user_name) const` (create new instance and return to pybind11, return `nullptr` if no user exists)
- `std::optional<UserModel> get_user2(const std::string &user_name) const` (return copy of instance to pybind11, return `std::nullopt` if no user exists)

Personally, I prefer the second API since it's avoid raw pointer.